# How to show cookie value in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there any way to show cookie value in ASP.NET Webforms, I tried something like the code below in ASP.NET MVC and it worked, but I'm wondering how I can do that in Webforms.

```
     <%if (Request.Cookies["name"] != null)
                {%>
            <small><strong>Hello <%Request.Cookies["name"].Value.ToString();%>, Welcome!</strong></small>
            <%}
                else
                { %>
```

This code above doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the Cookie's value on the page with `<%=Request.Cookies["name"].Value%>` (notice the `%=`), but you can't do conditional blocks like that like you can in MVC.  So you'll have to put it in a `Panel` and control the "visibility" server-side:

```
<asp:Panel ID="CookiePanel" runat="server">
   <small><strong>Hello <%=Request.Cookies["name"].Value.ToString()%>, Welcome!</strong></asp:Panel>

</div>
```

Then in your code-behind, probably in your `Page_OnLoad` you would add code like this:

```
CookiePanel.Visible = (Request.Cookies["name"] != null);
```

Note that when you set a server-side component's `Visible` property to `false`, the component won't be rendered at all on the client-side, so you won't get NullReference errors when the Cookie doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you would have to get the cookie on page load and then set it on the page.

[This](https://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/cookies/) article might help.